# Equivalence of two metrics defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: metric-spaces

The two metrics $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ are said to be topologically equivalent if they generate the same topology.

Suppose 
$d_1(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1 )^2+(x_2-y_2 )^2}$ (euclidean distance)

$d_2(x,y) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  |y_1-y_2 |  & \mbox{if } x_1 = x_2 \\
  |y_1 |+|y_2 |+|x_1-x_2 | & \mbox{if } x_1 \neq x_2
 \end{array}
\right.$

How I can conclude whether $d_1$ is equivalent to $d_2$ or not ?

Comment: Normally you look at the $\epsilon$-balls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $(\frac1n,1)$ converges to $(0,1)$ with respect to $d_1$, but not with respect to $d_2$ because
$$ d_2\left((\tfrac1n,1),(0,1)\right)=2+\frac1n.$$

Comment: thanks for your answer. Here you have proved that they are not equivalent but how I can prove that two metrics are equivalent? It would be very useful for me if you have example.

Answer (score 0):

Take $$x = \left(1,1\right)^T \text{ and } y=\left(2,2\right)^T$$

Then $$d_2(x,y) = 0$$ but $$x\neq y$$

Thus $d_2$ **is not** even **a metric** on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Are you sure you wrote down the task correctly?

Comment: the two points are like this (x1,y1) and (x2.y2) so for x=(1,1) and y=(2,2). d2(x,y)= 4 not 0 as you said . please review your answer.

Comment: @MotasemM.Al-wazir Then $d_1$ is not a metric with the same argument

Comment: both of them are metrics . please check the three conditions for metric

Comment: No, they are not. Check the definitions in your question, there is something wrong (maybe just a typo),

Comment: thanks for you interest but the Hagen's answer is correct for the question